# how to make my select query faster in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I've got a table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `pdd_data` (
    `pdd_id` INT(16) NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
    `vin` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `cmd` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `data` varchar(128) NOT NULL
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I insert 1,000,000 records into `pdd_data`, and I'll use queries frequently in the future as below:

```
select * from pdd_data where cmd = 4599;
select * from pdd_data where vin = 400;
select * from pdd_data where vin = 400 and cmd = 4599;
```

Currently, the query time is about 1.20sec~1.90sec. Could anyone give me some suggestions on how to make this query faster?

**p.s.** I create a table using index:

```
CREATE TABLE `pdd_data1` (
    `pdd_id` INT(16) NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
    `vin` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `cmd` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `data` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    index idx_vin_cmd (vin(32), cmd(16))
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But no improvement on `select` query.

Comment: You can add indexes to the cmd and vin individual fields. Try if it helps.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` command can help you optimize your tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: i wonder if adding of unique constraint helped in faster response...

Comment: InnoDB clusters by primary key. This affects access time. Therefore, do not make something a primary key _if you don't want that to be the primary key_. Also, in addition to creating proper, small incides (indexing 32 characters is probably way too much, try 4 or 5), use proper column types. Smaller indices and smaller constant-size data types are faster. You seem to be using `cmd` and `vin` only with integers, but they are of `varchar` type. If something is an integer, the column type should be integer.

Comment: @Damon, good spot on the keys. MySQL seems to ignore a key on a VARCHAR column if it is specified in the SQL without quotes. Found this when someone designed a table with a timestamp stored in a VARCHAR field, but then searched for the timestamp without quotes. Adding quotes made a massive difference (and if I had been able to change the column to an INT I suspect the difference would have been even greater)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is do not use `select *`. Instead of using `select *` use `select pdd_id, vin,time, cmd, data`. This will definitely reduce your execution time.